# Capacitance of Non-concentric Spheres

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

We all know how to obtain the capacitance $C=\frac{ab}{b-a}$ (ignoring constants) for two concentric spheres of radii $a,b$.

I was just thinking to myself, **what would happen to the capacitance for non-concentric spheres?**
Suppose we perturbed the inner sphere off the origin.  Does capacitance increase?  Ideally I would be looking for an explicit calculation (under sufficiently nice assumptions) but I am also guessing it would be a rather ugly formula.

Comment: We know that the system is unstable. After you perturb the inner sphere, it'll move all the way until it touches the outer sphere. Since the potential energy is $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$, and it's decreasing along the way -> the capacitance increases

Comment: Here is my estimate for the change in potential energy $\approx U_0 (\frac{\delta}{b})^2$ (I got this from the change in $\frac12 E^2 2\pi b^2 \delta$). This gives us $\frac{\delta C}{C}\approx (\frac{\delta}{b})^2$. Not sure

Comment: @pcr: I do not see why the system is unstable... Irregardless, I am defining my region, with boundaries of the conductors! So everything is held fixed!

Comment: I cheated by using Earnshaw theorem =) (the system is unstable if you don't nail down the conductors). Alternatively, you can also argue by drawing the E-field line: the lines in the "forward pole" region (using Georg's convention) are denser than those in the "backward pole" region, which suggests an attraction.

Comment: But Earnshaw's theorem will only talk about how charges spread out amongst the surfaces; even if I let the conductors "move" there are normal forces (boundary conditions) so that Earnshaw doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Check section III and figures 5 to 9 of [this note](http://www.ece.unm.edu/summa/notes/SSN/note171.pdf).

Comment: Hmm okay. The capacitance only depends on the geometry & electrostatic boundary of the system. I think the normal force on the system is not one of them (it's more  of a dynamical boundary condition) -> it doesn't specify any potential. So I can still use Earnshaw to know the direction of the force.

Comment: No; Earnshaw applies when *only* electrostatic forces are involved... that is not the case here.  If anything, Earnshaw will tell you that the charges redistribute themselves across the two surfaces.

Comment: Sorry for my messy/incomplete argument. Sure, electrostatic+normal force = stable, but the elctrostatic part by itself isn't be stable (I guess you already know about this one). The inner conductor is already attracted to the outer conductor before the redistribution. Redistribution will only increase the attraction.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say... "the electrostatic part being unstable" is *irrelevant* because there isn't just an electrostatic part... You cannot simply ignore the boundaries.  Earnshaw does no good here.

Comment: See http://iopscience.iop.org/1402-4896/2/3/001 and references therein.

Comment: That reference is for two spheres that are separated from each other (externally) by a distance...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Important notice: My previous result was a little bit incorrect. I found the factor $1/2$ by comparison with the textbook V.V. Batygin, I.N. Toptygin *«Problems in electrodynamics»*.**

Let's denote the radius of the inner sphere $S_1$ as $a$, the radius of the outer
sphere $S_2$ as $b$ and the displacement as $c$, so that $c\ll a,b$. We choose the
origin of the coordinate system to be in the center of the inner sphere. Then,
up to the second order in $c$ the distance from the origin to the outer sphere
has the form:
$$
R\left(  \theta\right)  =b+c\cos\theta.
$$
Therefore, the potential in the space between them can be found as
$$
\phi=\left(  \alpha_{1}+\frac{\beta_{1}}{r}\right)  +c\left(  \alpha
_{2}r+\frac{\beta_{2}}{r^{2}}\right)  \cos\theta,
$$
where $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{i}$ are constant which should be found from the
boundary conditions:
$$
\left.  \phi\right\vert _{S_{1}}=const,\quad\left.  \phi\right\vert _{S_{2}
}=0,\quad
\oint_{S_{1}}
\mathrm{d}S\,\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\phi=-4\pi Q,\,
$$
where $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{r}/r$. Hence the potential reads as follows:
$$
\phi=Q\left(  \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{b}\right)  +\frac{Qc}{b^{3}-c^{3}}\left(
r-\frac{a^{3}}{r^{2}}\right)  \cos\theta.
$$
Therefore the potential on the inner sphere doesn't depend on $c$ up to the
second order:
$$
\left.  \phi\right\vert _{S_{1}}=Q\,\frac{b-a}{ab}.
$$
The charge distribution on the inner sphere can be found as follows:
$$
\sigma=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(  \mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\phi\right)
=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\left.  \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\,\phi\right\vert
_{r=a}=\frac{Q}{4\pi a^{2}}\left(  1-\frac{3a^{2}c}{b^{3}-c^{3}}\cos
\theta\right)  .
$$
Hence, the force acting on the inner sphere has the form:
$$
\mathbf{F}=-\frac{1}{2}\oint_{S_{1}} \mathrm{d}S\,\sigma\mathbf{\nabla}\phi,
$$
$$
F   =-\frac{Q^{2}}{4}\int_{-1}^{1}\mathrm{d}\cos\theta\,\left(
1-\frac{3ca^{2}}{b^{3}-c^{3}}\cos\theta\right)  \left.  \frac{\partial
}{\partial z}\left[  \frac{1}{r}+\frac{c}{b^{3}-c^{3}}\left(  1-\frac{a^{3}
}{r^{3}}\right)  z\right]  \right\vert _{r=a}\\
 =-\,\frac{Q^{2}c}{b^{3}-c^{3}},
$$
where I use the trivial identity:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{1}{r^{n}}=-\frac{nz}{r^{3}}.
$$
The capacity $C$ can be found from the potential energy:
$$
U=\frac{CV^{2}}{2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad F=-\frac{\Delta U}{\Delta c}
=-\frac{\phi^{2}}{2}\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta c},
$$
thus
$$
\frac{\Delta C}{\Delta c}=-\frac{2F}{\phi^{2}}=\frac{2ca^{2}b^{2}}{\left(
b^{3}-a^{3}\right)  \left(  a-b\right)  ^{2}}.
$$
Finally, we obtain
$$
C=\frac{ab}{b-a}+\frac{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}}{\left(  b^{3}-a^{3}\right)  \left(
a-b\right)  ^{2}}\quad\quad (1)
$$

**UPDATE:** The comments given above give the reference to the article of *«Capacitance Bounds for Geometries Corresponding to an Advanced Simulator Design»* by M.I. Sancer and A.D. Varvatsis. The article in turn contains the reference to the book:

> W. R. Smythe, *Static and Dynamic Electricity*, McGraw-Hill, New York,
>   1950

where the following exact result for the capacitance is presented:
$$
C=ab\sinh\alpha\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b\sinh n\alpha-a\sinh\left(
n-1\right)  \alpha},\quad\quad\left(  2\right)
$$
so that
$$
\quad\cosh\alpha=\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}-c^{2}}{2ab}.
$$
Sancer and Varvatsis claim that they found the approximation of the exact
result in the $c\rightarrow0$ limit:
$$
C=\frac{ab}{b-a}\left[  \frac{1}{2}\left(  \sqrt{\frac{1-y^{2}/\left(
1+x\right)  ^{2}}{1-y^{2}/\left(  1-x\right)^{2}}}+1\right) + \frac{x}{2}\left(  \sqrt{\frac{1-y^{2}/\left(  1+x\right)  ^{2}}{1-y^{2}/\left(
1-x\right)  ^{2}}}-1\right)  \right]  ,\quad\quad\left(  3\right)
$$
where
$$
x=\frac{a}{b},\quad y=\frac{c}{b}.
$$
It is easy to see that the expansion of the result (3) doesn't coincide with
mine result (1). The numerical comparison of all three results presented in
the figure below:

[image: the comparison of the three results: exact (2), mine (1) and Sancer and Varvatsis (3)]

One can see that the result (3) of Sancer and Varvatsis is incorrect.

Comment: In one of the above comments, a paper was referenced, and it shows that: Letting $d$ denote the distance between the spheres' centers, $C\sim 4\pi\varepsilon\frac{ab}{b-a}\cdot F$, where $F=\frac{1}{2}[\sqrt{\frac{1-(\frac{d}{a+b})^2}{1-(\frac{d}{b-a})^2}}+1]+\frac{1}{2}\frac{a}{b}[\sqrt{\frac{1-(\frac{d}{a+b})^2}{1-(\frac{d}{b-a})^2}}-1]$. Does your approximation fit with this? Sorry I'm being lazy.

Comment: @ChrisGerig I added the comparison with the article you mentioned.

Comment: +1, nice answer! Although you leave the limit of large c undiscussed.

Comment: @GrishaKirilin Will you please explain the 2nd equation (right after the line: "Therefore, the potential in the space between them can be found as")? One or two extra lines will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The whole system is unstable (you can convince yourself by Earnshaw theorem or by drawing the field lines). After you perturb the inner sphere, it'll move all the way until it touches the outer sphere. Since the potential energy is $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$, and it's decreasing along the way -> the capacitance increases.

Here is my estimate for the change in potential energy $\approx -U_0 \frac{b-a}{a}(\frac{\delta}{b})^2$ .

I got this from the change in bulk electrostatic energy $\frac12 E^2 2\pi b^2\delta$

[image]

Here I shift the outer conductor because it is easier to follow my calculation this way. The shift is exaggerated for clarity's sake.

Initially, the electrostatic energy comes from region 1 and 2. After the shift, it comes from region 2 and 3. We can roughly see that the energy in region 3 is less than the one in region 1: region 1 is nearer to the inner conductor than region 3.

Clearly the change in energy is

$$U_3 - U_1 = \frac12 (E_3^2 -E_1^2) 2\pi b^2 \delta$$
with
$$E_3^2 - E_1^2 \approx 2E_1 \frac{dE}{dr} \delta \approx -4 E_1^2 \frac{\delta}b$$

we get
$$U_3 - U_1 = - \frac{e^2}{4\pi b} (\frac{\delta}b)^2= U_0 \frac{b-a}a (\frac{\delta}b)^2$$

This gives us $-\frac{\Delta U}{U}=\frac{\Delta C}C\approx\frac{b-a}{a}(\frac{\delta}{b})^2$.

Comment: See my comment above, I do not see how Earnshaw is sufficiently applied, because there are *not* only electrostatic forces here... And the field lines argument is not rigorous so it *could* be incorrect.   But in addition, I would like to see your energy change calculation as well.

Comment: @pcr, I erased my comment when I realized that Chris knows better than any answer, especially when he wrote ""especially when these are rings moving in weird ways (or just rings moving towards the other sphere?) and not planes moving closer to each other..."". He lacks imagination of the one-dimensional nature of the problem.